# Pandas: Checking to see if an entry in a pandas dataframe column is empty

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have a dataframe with numbers that are of type float. How would you check if there is an entry that is empty?

Example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(.21, ), (.01, .67), (.66, .03), (.21, .18)],
                  columns=['dogs', 'cats'])
```

No there cannot be NAN's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to replace NaN with whatever you want:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df

   dogs  cats
0  0.21  0.00
1  0.01  0.67
2  0.66  0.03
3  0.21  0.18
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isna` with `any`

```
df.isna().any()
Out[103]: 
dogs    False
cats     True
dtype: bool
```

Or from `info` , you can know  is the non-null is not equal to dataframe length

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
dogs    4 non-null float64
cats    3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 192.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run that command, the blank would itself become NaN. So I am not sure what your output would be? You want NaN to disappear? you can do this:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(.21, ), (.01, .67), (.66, .03), (.21, .18)],
                  columns=['dogs', 'cats']).fillna(" ")
```

output :- 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`[index for index,row in df.iterrows() if any(np.isnan(row))]`

by iterating all rows, this can show you the indices of rows with an empty